# How can i make keep the value of a variable constant from module to string?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, passwords, global-variables

I have been trying to create this password protection type thing in excel VBA for Applied ICT project. So I have created this module which protects all the sheet in the work books:

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim psword As String

psword = "Unit 12"
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:=psword
Next ws

End Sub
```

Now the thing that i want to do is that whenever someone will open an userform an inputbox asking for the password will appear and if someone enters an invalid password a message box would appear. It will be something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
x = InputBox("Please type in the password", "Password")
If x = psword Then
Call Module1.Sheets_unlock
Else
Msgbox("The password is invalid")
End
End If
End If
```

Now the problem is the of password changes to nothing in the UserForm_Activate() sub. I have tried the public psword as string, but it doesn't work. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Its where you **Dim** it.

Dim psword in a standard module above all other subs in the module like:

```
Public psword As String
```

Comment: Well, i have tried using this but still the same result. In the userform_activate sub the value of psword changes back to nil.